# Realtime stdout/stderr from Dockerized Ubuntu bash session (async ssh with trio)

Tags: docker, ssh, python-asyncio, python-trio

I need to ssh into a docker container (ubuntu/bash) and access stdout/stderr as it is emmitted (rather than wait for the entire command to complete then pick it up).

I found `asyncssh` which appears to be asyncio-based. GPT4 suggests:

```py
import asyncio
import asyncssh

async def run_command():
    container = client.containers.run(
        'my-ssh-image',
        name='my-ssh-container',
        detach=True,
        remove=False,
        auto_remove=False,
        ports={'22/tcp': ('127.0.0.1', 2222)},
        publish_all_ports=True,
    )

    async with asyncssh.connect('127.0.0.1', 2222, username='root', password='password') as conn:
        async with conn.create_process('echo "foo"') as process:
            while not process.stdout.at_eof():
                stdout_line = await process.stdout.readline()
                if stdout_line:
                    print(' stdout:')
                    print(stdout_line.strip())

                stderr_line = await process.stderr.readline()
                if stderr_line:
                    print('stderr:')
                    print(stderr_line.strip())

    container.stop()
    container.remove()

asyncio.run(run_command())
```

However I can't see any way to do this with trio, other than using `asyncio_trio` to wrap the aio-flavoured calls. And I prefer to use trio over asyncio.

`trio` seems to be lacking an ssh lib.

How to achieve an async ssh session with trio?